# Не перебрасываются элементы из списка в словарь. Почему?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, циклы

Объясните ошибку, пожалуйста. Я хочу, чтобы элементы из списка переходили в словарь и их ключами были бы их порядковые номера, но при этом, если элемент из списка повторяется, то мы его просто пропускаем. Как это реализовывается. Я сделал так

```
def enumerate(data, counter):
    tpl = {}
    for element in data:
        if element not in tpl:
            tpl[counter] = element
            counter += 1
        else:
            pass
    return tpl
data1 = [8, 7, 5, 7, 4, 7, 6, 3]
for i in enumerate(data1, 1):
    print(i)
```

но ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ведь возвращаете словарь, а при его переборе в `for` будут возвращаться ключ, а чтобы получить ключ-значение, используйте метод `items`:

```
...

data1 = [8, 7, 5, 7, 4, 7, 6, 3]

for i in enumerate(data1, 1).items():
    print(i)
# (1, 8)
# (2, 7)
# (3, 5)
# (4, 7)
# (5, 7)
# (6, 6)

# Или так:
for i, x in enumerate(data1, 1).items():
    print(i, x)
```

Или в функции возвращайте результат как:

```
    return tpl.items()
```

---

**PS.**

`enumerate` это встроенная функция, лучше не называйте свою функцию также, чтобы не получать сюрпризы в коде, где используется встроенный `enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

Видимо потому что у вас задан диапазон старт и стопа в цикле, попробуйте оставить лишь `data1`, а еще в питоне уже есть метод `enumerate` если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Я просто хочу сам написать enumerate. Но ведь это не диапазон старта и стопа, а список и счетчик. Если убрать единицу, ничего не заработает.